# store data to multiple tables with foreign keys in "store function" in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables called tournaments, rounds & pools. Rounds table has a foreign key tournament_id and Pools table has a round_id foreign key. I have a form where I can create a round and a pool at the same time. I usually add data to database is using the store function of a particular controller using a $request.

Example: This is in the PoolController.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pool = new Pool;
    $pool->name = $request->poolName;
    // $pool->round_id = $request->Roundname;

    $pool->save();

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

Here I don't know how to deal with the round_id. When the Create button pressed, the new round and the pool must be created at the same time and that round id must be assigned to $pool->round_id.

Any help please?

Comment: You cannot create the entries at the same time, the round record has to be created first.

Comment: you mean in the Round controller I should create a new Round in the store function and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. I did this for Round creation. For that we need to first create the tournament. Then in the Round Controller I did the below code

```
use App\Round;
use App\Tournament;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $round = new Round;
    $round->name = $request->roundName;

    $tournament = new Tournament;
    $tournamentName = $request->tournamentName;
    $tournament = $tournament::where('name', $tournamentName)->firstOrFail();
    $tournament->rounds()->save($round);

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

Here round has a foreign key called tournament_id. How this works is when inserting a new round we are finding the corresponding tournament by

```
$tournament = $tournament::where('name', $tournamentName)->firstOrFail();
```

Then we call the relationship function rounds() in the Tournament Model to save the new round while updating the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

to save multiple foreign keys use aRRAY

```
$tournament = [
          'document_id' => $tournament->id,
            'name' => tournamentName   
   ];
```